# Why does my vue web app load a blank page in IE11 and look broken in Edge?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, polyfills, babel-polyfill

I'm having a bit of trouble with getting my project to work on IE11 and Edge

You can view it here: https://tagfireandsecurity.co.uk/

> **THE PROBLEMS**

**IE11:** Blank page, shows multiple errors:

```
SCRIPT1002: Syntax error
firebase-app.js (1,1)
SCRIPT1002: Syntax error
firebase-analytics.js (1,1)
SCRIPT1002: Syntax error
init.js (1,1)
SCRIPT5043: Accessing the 'caller' property of a function or arguments object is not allowed in strict mode
eval code (3959) (15268,9)
SCRIPT5022: SecurityError
sockjs.js (1684,3)
```

**Edge:** Loads the website, however its all messed up. For example the grid is not working and my carousels aren't working. Also shows some errors:

```
SCRIPT65535: SCRIPT65535: Invalid calling object
```

> **WHAT I'VE DONE SO FAR**

I tried to make sure babel will polyfill which I don't even know if it's doing it to be honest, I followed the documentation on their website and I don't think its working.

I also tried to add `transpileDependencies: ['vue-mq', 'vue-carousel', 'firebase', 'vue-lazyload-video']` to polyfill my plugins but I don't think that is doing anything either.

I also added an autoprefixer and I believe that is working because the SCSS to CSS output now has all the prefixes in it, so why it's not working in EDGE? I don't know. Inspecting it in Edge shows it has the prefixes there, sometimes just disabling the prefix and putting it back on again fixes it so I'm very confused.

**Here are my config files:**

> babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    presets: [
        ['@vue/app', {
            polyfills: [
                'es.promise',
                'es.symbol'
            ]
        }]
    ]
};
```

> webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [
                'style-loader',
                { loader: 'css-loader', options: { importLoaders: 1 } },
                'postcss-loader'
            ]
        }],
        vue: {
            // configure autoprefixer
            autoprefixer: {
                browsers: ['last 2 versions']
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> vue.config.js

```
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
    transpileDependencies: ['vue-mq', 'vue-carousel', 'firebase', 'vue-lazyload-video']
}
```

> main.ts

```
import "core-js/stable";
import "regenerator-runtime/runtime";
require('intersection-observer');
import "regenerator-runtime/runtime";
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
import store from "./store";
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css";
import VueMq from "vue-mq";
import { gsap } from "gsap";
import { ScrollTrigger } from "gsap/ScrollTrigger";
import VueCarousel from "vue-carousel";
import "animate.css/animate.css";
import * as firebase from "firebase";
import VueLazyLoadVideo from "vue-lazyload-video";
require("intersection-observer");
require("matchmedia-polyfill");
require("matchmedia-polyfill/matchMedia.addListener");
import "lazysizes";
import "lazysizes/plugins/parent-fit/ls.parent-fit";
import "lazysizes/plugins/blur-up/ls.blur-up";

// Register Components
// LazyVideo & LazyVideoAsGIF
Vue.use(VueLazyLoadVideo);

const firebaseConfig = {
  HIDDEN CONFIG FOR STACKOVERFLOW
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

Vue.use(VueCarousel);

gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);

Vue.use(VueMq, {
  breakpoints: {
    // default breakpoints - customize this
    sm: 480,
    md: 921,
    lg: 1024
  }
});

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

> postcss.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        require('autoprefixer')({})
    ]
};
```

> package.json

```
{
    "name": "tag",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
        "build": "vue-cli-service build",
        "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@firebase/polyfill": "^0.3.36",
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.13.0",
        "animate.css": "^4.1.0",
        "axios": "^0.19.2",
        "core-js": "^3.6.5",
        "firebase": "^7.15.5",
        "gsap": "^3.4.0",
        "intersection-observer": "^0.11.0",
        "lazysizes": "^5.2.2",
        "matchmedia-polyfill": "^0.3.2",
        "uuid": "^8.2.0",
        "vue": "^2.6.11",
        "vue-carousel": "^0.18.0",
        "vue-class-component": "^7.2.3",
        "vue-lazyload-video": "^0.1.15",
        "vue-mq": "^1.0.1",
        "vue-property-decorator": "^8.4.2",
        "vue-router": "^3.2.0",
        "vuex": "^3.4.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.10.4",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.33.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.33.0",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^4.4.6",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.4.0",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.4.0",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "~4.4.0",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~4.4.0",
        "@vue/cli-service": "~4.4.0",
        "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^6.0.0",
        "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^5.0.2",
        "autoprefixer": "^9.8.5",
        "cssnano": "^4.1.10",
        "eslint": "^6.7.2",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.3",
        "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
        "fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.5",
        "google-auth-library": "^6.0.5",
        "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
        "postcss-import": "^12.0.1",
        "postcss-load-config": "^2.1.0",
        "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
        "postcss-preset-env": "^6.7.0",
        "prettier": "^1.19.1",
        "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
        "sugarss": "^2.0.0",
        "typescript": "~3.9.3",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "root": true,
        "env": {
            "node": true
        },
        "extends": [
            "plugin:vue/essential",
            "eslint:recommended",
            "@vue/typescript/recommended",
            "@vue/prettier",
            "@vue/prettier/@typescript-eslint"
        ],
        "parserOptions": {
            "ecmaVersion": 2020
        },
        "rules": {}
    },
    "browserslist": [
        "last 1 version",
        "> 1%",
        "IE 10"
    ]
}
```

> tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "allowJs": true,
    "strict": false,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "types": [
      "webpack-env"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    },
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "scripthost"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Unhelpful (sorry) but true answer: because they suck. Know you're not alone: we've all been there.

Comment: @JaredSmith you mean my web app or the browsers haha? I am new to web development so my website does suck. 
And in terms of the browsers, yeah they really do, I"m tempted to just try and fix the Edge issue and leave IE11 because it's killing me

Comment: You can have a disclaimer on your web app that it doesn't work properly in Edge and IE 11.

Comment: @squish the browsers for sure. Your web app I don't know, but it's a whole lot easier to fix that than an almost decade old web browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to say this, you can't render a website built with JS based framework (VUE, ReactJS etc) in IE, and the JS engine of Edge (non-chromium) is not capable of handling all features of ES6 standard. If the customer wants to use your website on a Microsoft based browser, then they have to switch to the latest Edge based on Chromium.

Comment: Good advice. ... But perhaps this should be in comments

Comment: I think this is the way to go to be honest. Thanks for the help!

Comment: this is not entirely true as there are examples of vue apps running on ie 11