# When my Vue app doesn't render on IE11, how can I display a disclaimer screen?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, internet-explorer-11

my app was developed in Vue and currently it doesn't work great in IE11 and old edge, I can render a "please update your browser screen" on edge because the app will load somewhat, however IE11 just shows a blank screen.

How can I check to see if the user is on IE11 and then just render a plain HTML/CSS page that asks them to update their browser?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have met this kind of issue before. I detect the browser version and if IE then render some messages you need. If not IE then render the vue app.

I use JavaScript in **public/index.html** to detect browser, the code is like below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
   <link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon.ico">
   <title>my-vue-app</title>
 </head>
 <body>
   <noscript>
     <strong>We're sorry but my-vue-app doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
   </noscript>
   <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
   <script type="text/javascript">
     function get_browser() {
       var ua = navigator.userAgent, tem, M = ua.match(/(opera|chrome|safari|firefox|msie|trident(?=\/))\/?\s*(\d+)/i) || [];
       if (/trident/i.test(M[1])) {
         tem = /\brv[ :]+(\d+)/g.exec(ua) || [];
         return { name: 'IE', version: (tem[1] || '') };
       }
       if (M[1] === 'Chrome') {
         tem = ua.match(/\bOPR\/(\d+)/)
         if (tem != null) { return { name: 'Opera', version: tem[1] }; }
       }
       if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Edge") > -1) {
         tem = ua.match(/\Edge\/(\d+)/)
         if (tem != null) { return { name: 'Edge', version: tem[1] }; }      
       }
       M = M[2] ? [M[1], M[2]] : [navigator.appName, navigator.appVersion, '-?'];
       if ((tem = ua.match(/version\/(\d+)/i)) != null) { M.splice(1, 1, tem[1]); }
       return {
         name: M[0],
         version: +M[1]
       };
     }

     var browser = get_browser()
     var isSupported = isSupported(browser);

     function isSupported(browser) {
       var supported = false;
       if (browser.name === "Chrome" && browser.version >= 48) {
         supported = true;
       } else if ((browser.name === "MSIE" || browser.name === "IE") && browser.version <= 11) {
         supported = false;
       } else if (browser.name === "Edge") {
         supported = true;
       }
       return supported;
     }

     if (!isSupported) {
       //render unsupported message
       document.write("<h1>The app is not supported in IE. Please use other browsers!</h1>");
     }
     else{
       //render app
       var elem = document.createElement("div");
       elem.setAttribute("id", "app")
       document.body.appendChild(elem);
     }
   </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wow I didn't even think of using the public.html to do this. It's so obvious now! 谢谢哥

Comment: This is a great solution! Just an FYI - your code displays the not supported message in the latest versions of Firefox and Opera as well as IE for me. Since my app by default supports any browser except for IE11 and lower, I made a tiny change to your code and let "supported" start out as true by default:

var supported = true;

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to, have you tried this:
https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/browser-compatibility.html#browserslist ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62919745/why-does-my-vue-web-app-load-a-blank-page-in-ie11-and-look-broken-in-edge/62920093#62920093 this was my original post and it seems it's not possible to make my website work on legacy browsers

Comment: my bad, i only have experience with vue as components, not rendering a whole page. I thought this wouldn' make any major difference. Sorry.